# How to refer to values (re-use values) of `data` of the plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a barplot -

```
df <- data.frame(xpos=c(200, 300, 400, 600),
                 ypos=c(  1,   3,   2,   1))
gp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=xpos, y=ypos)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

and want to make a line connecting, say, bars 1, 3 and 2. I succeed to do this if I define `data` through the original dataframe `df`:

```
gp +
  geom_path(data=data.frame(xpos=c(df$xpos[1], df$xpos[3], df$xpos[2]),
                            ypos=c(df$ypos[1], df$ypos[3], df$ypos[2])))
```

But what if I can't/don't want to refer to the source dataframe and rather want to use values of previously defined `data`? I tried the following:

```
gp +
  geom_path(data=data.frame(xpos=c(xpos[1], xpos[3], xpos[2]),
                            ypos=c(ypos[1], ypos[3], ypos[2])))
# object 'xpos' not found

gp +
  geom_path(data=aes(xpos=c(xpos[1], xpos[3], xpos[2]), 
                     ypos=c(ypos[1], ypos[3], ypos[2]))
            )
# ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to just take the data from the gp object explicitly:

```
gp + geom_path(data=gp$data[c(1,3,2),])
```

Comment: oh, that simple! Thanks!